# NullPointerException while initializing a path

Tags: querydsl

i got  `NullPointerException` while i try execute this code

```
QFournisseur.fournisseur.adresse.ville.province
```

i try according to [doc](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.1.1/reference/html/ch03s04.html) add @QueryInit annotation in

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Fournisseur implements java.io.Serializable {

    ...
    @QueryInit("ville")
    private Adresse adresse;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class Adresse implements java.io.Serializable {

    ..
    @QueryInit("province")
    private Ville ville;
```

but it didn't work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is solved now by putting `@QueryInit` in `Fournisseur` :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_ADRESSE")
@QueryInit("ville.province.region")
public Adresse getAdresse() {
    return this.adresse;
}
```

to get in `QFournisseur`

```
private static final PathInits INITS = new PathInits("*", "adresse.ville.province.region");
```